# Can superposition of ultrasound and hearable sound be heard differently in comparison to the same hearable sound without superpositioned ultrasound?

Tags: acoustics

On recent audio show, I have noted down 5 rooms where sound was the best to my ears, so I can make second round to hear them again. After few days, when analysing speakers used in these 5 rooms, all of the speakers were capable of reproducing music over hearable human range, sometimes to 50 kHz.
One explanation is that these super tweeters are only doing better job inside hearable range, and my question is:
If superposition of many ultrasound waves (usualy overharmonics on every instrument) can lead to wave shape which is hearable? We know that discrette ultrasound pitches cannot be heard.
So, we are hearing then influence of unhearable pitches?
Thank you!
Silvio

Comment: It seems quite unlikely that the music source driving the speakers had any actual content above 22.05 kHz (the top end of CDs).

Comment: Even if what @JonCuster is not true (which I strongly believe it is), have you considered how loud the higher order harmonics ("overharmonics" is an awful term in my opinion) of the instruments at the very high end (let’s say close or even higher than $20 ~ kHz$) are for you ear to be able to perceive them? I don’t think the reproduction of those frequencies makes a huge difference (I actually think they make **no** difference). Still, extended frequency response is usually accompanied by high linearity in these frequencies which may (I believe it does) have a significant quality impact.

Comment: It is well known that even vinyl has up to 50 kHz content - see example of spectrogram on https://www.pbase.com/rsub8/image/43900570

Comment: Additional good readings, which prove that when properly sampled orchestral music with distant mics can capture frequencies up to 96 kHz. Mostly brass and percusion: https://www.stereophile.com/features/282/index.html